# Is it possible to search though all xcodes logs

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

XCode now keeps the logs from the previous runs handy which is great.

[image]

Is there a way to search though all of the logs.

My use case is I have seen a particular error but cant remember which run it was in.  I need to find the error URL from the logs.

Comment: I can do a custom search from within XCode on a folder... Just a case of finding the logs folder now!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Xcode stores debug logs at

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<YOURAPP>/Logs/Debug/
```

The `.xcactivitylog` files are actually just `gz` archives. Decompress them:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<YOURAPP>/Logs/Debug/
EXT=".xcactivitylog"
for LOG in *.xcactivitylog; do
    NAME=`basename $LOG $EXT`
    gunzip -c -S $EXT "${NAME}${EXT}" > "${NAME}.log"
done
```

Now you can easily search them using `grep` or `Spotlight` or what your prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The folder where these logs are is

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[YOURAPPID]/Logs/Debug/
```

You can open/read/search them for example in [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Answer (score 2):

To add onto @DrummerB answer.  Once the files are unziped you can do a search with custom scope from within XCode.  I prefer this to grep or spotlight.

[image]

[image]

[image]