# Output of UI tests when running tests in parallell

Tags: ios, xctest, xcodebuild, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to run UI tests in parallell from the command line using xcodebuild.

The command I'm using is:

```
xcodebuild 
     -verbose 
     -workspace "MyWorkspace.xcworkspace" 
     -scheme "User Interface Tests" 
     -sdk iphonesimulator 
     -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=5193368C-B000-4ED1-99F6-E23F7BAB9F69' 
     -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=9B751E0D-8268-4DDF-ADAC-CBF2508F4CCC'
     test
```

The test execution works fine on both devices, but I can't see any log messages anywhere. I.e.

> t =    25.90s     Tap "MenuButton" Button
>   t =    25.90s         Wait for no.test.myapp to idle
>   t =    26.14s         Find the "MenuButton" Button
>   t =    26.35s             Wait for no.test.myapp to idle
>   t =    26.39s         Synthesize event
>   t =    26.46s         Wait for no.test.myapp to idle
>   t =    27.09s     Tap "FooBar" StaticText

When I only have one destination I can see the log/output of the test (the same output you can see when running tests from Xcode). However, when I add a second destination, the only information that's shown is:

> Test case '`Foo.testBar()` passed on iPhone 8'

or

> Test case '`Foo.testBar()` failed on iPhone 6s'.

This is not very helpful as I would like to know where in the test it failed.

Is this output being logged anywhere? Ideally I would like to see the step-by-step log for each device I run the test on.

Comment: I use bluepill (https://github.com/linkedin/bluepill) to manage my GUI testing and it deals with log messages (even in parallel runs).  You could use it (highly recommended) or I guess, look at the code to see how it does that.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into using Bluebill!

Comment: I developed a tool that build an HTML report based on the results of the tests. It works when running tests in parallel. https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCUITestHTMLReport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be an .xcactivitylog in your derived data folder, which is usually at the following path:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<your-app-name>/Logs/Test/
```

If you've done lots of test runs recently, you'll see a few different logs; feel free to remove these before each test run to keep the directory clean and easy to navigate.

Comment: Thanks. For Xcode and iOS novices like me, to open .xcactivitylog files I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861658/is-it-possible-to-search-though-all-xcodes-logs

Comment: @CF256 I believe your comment should be part of the answer! At first I saw the answer but missed the comment... then I kept searching and came here again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can control the location of your TestSummaries.plist (which you can feed to `xchtmlreport`) by adding this flag to your xcodebuild command:

`-resultBundlePath resultsDir`

You should remove the folder between each test run. If you are going to run in parallel, you will probably want a separate results path for each xcodebuild invocation.